# Java robust way to deal with String absolute path

Tags: java, unit-testing, absolute-path

In my Java application, the user can give the absolute path of a file (that he wants the application to read and do stuff with) through some configuration file.

This path is stored in a `String`, and I have a method like

```
public void readFile(String filePath){
    // read the file using its absolute path then do stuff
}
```

**My point is** : I don't know if a user will give me a path like

- `C:/my/path/myfile.ext`

or like

- `C:\my\path\myfile.ext`

(assuming it's a Windows user).

*Is there a consistent way to deal with it?*

*or should I force users to choose one or the other way? and in this case: which one is best?*

Comment: Why not force the user to use File or Path? Like using `JFileChooser` or something alike, as other programs do? For both cases, File and Path, addressing details will not pose a problem, with some exceptions of virtually mounted network drives... Or simply convert your String into `File` or `Path`, and check it from there...

Comment: First you should separate the internal handling from the user perspective. It shouldn't matter what the user does. So technically I would suggest to user `Path` instead because it handles the OS dependent things much better and easier than `File` does. The user should be able to type of them and it should work.. (Write the test for both cases and see how `Path` handles that...

Comment: @JayC667 In my case, the app launches a quite heavy batch process that the user can unfortunately not directly start by himself, but must have an approval before that app actually starts. The user gives a config file with the path of files to be processed. Even though both ways seem to work as I'm testing, I'm a bit concerned about how this will be in prod. I will consider using something like `JFileChooser` (eventually on a separate module) to make the user get it right.

Comment: @khmarbaise `Paths.get()` looks like the robust method I was looking for. Your comment also raises a point which was actually a part of my initial questioning : in unit-tests, can I test that my method is able to read a file using an absolute path ? I mean that I can't write a test case using an absolute path which would inherently be dependent of my local version (or can I ?).

Comment: If you class/method can read a configuration file it does not really matter if the path where it's read from absolute or relative. If you think you need to that you are starting to test the JDK instead of your own code. If you really like to write such a test you could do that via things like https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem or https://github.com/google/jimfs (But I think this is not necessary in your case). Furthermore you should separate things like getting information from the user (user input) and the technical services which do the work... (separation of concern).

Comment: `java.io.File` can already handle both cases (and even a mixture). Also have a look at `File.getAbsolutePath` and `File.getCanonicalPath`.